# Парсинг картинок товара WildBerries по ссылке на товар

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Задача заключается в том, чтобы имея ссылку на товар в WildBerries, автоматически парсить фотографии товара и сохранять их в определенную папку.
У меня же по какой-то причине загружается html код в html не страницы товара, а страницы загрузки, и я не понимаю, как этого избежать.

Моя попытка спарсить:

```
links = []
mg = []
if not os.path.exists(f'imgs/{message.chat.id}'):
     os.mkdir(f'imgs/{message.chat.id}')
url = requests.get(message.text).text
html = BS(url, 'lxml')
#print(html)
print(url)
main_block = html.find('div', {"class":"swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal"})
block = main_block.find('div', {"class":'swiper-wrapper'})
all_images = block.find_all('div', {"class":'swiper-slide img-plug'})
for image in all_images:
    image_link = 'https:' + image.get('data-zoom-image')
    links.append(image_link)
for i in range(len(links)):
    p = requests.get(links[i])
    out = open(f"imgs/{message.chat.id}/file_{i}.jpg", "wb")
    out.write(p.content)
    mg.append(f"imgs/{message.chat.id}/file_{i}.jpg")
    out.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.